# Control for Target Audience in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, audience-targeting

Can any one tell which control is working behind the scene for "Target Audience" in SharePoint 2010?
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The field supporting audience targeting is [Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.FieldTypes.SPFieldTargetTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.webcontrols.fieldtypes.spfieldtargetto.aspx).

The control for rendering the field is [Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.SPFieldTargetToControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.webcontrols.fieldtypes.spfieldtargettocontrol.aspx).

Comment: The links are for SharePoint 2013, but it is the same for SharePoint 2010.